# Inserting zeros in numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

A function that takes in a **vector** and returns a new vector where every element is separated by 4 consecutive zeros.

Example:

```
[4, 2, 1] --> [4,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,1]
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! For us to adequately assist you, it's helpful to see what you have attempted so far

Answer (score 3, accepted):

***Setup***

```
a = np.array([4, 2, 1])
```

---

Using slice assignment:

```
s = a.shape[0]
v = s + (4 * (s - 1))
f = np.zeros(v)

f[::5] = a
```

```
array([4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve it using the following!

```
import numpy as np

a = [4, 2, 1] 

new_a = np.zeros((len(a)-1)*5+1)

new_a [np.arange(0,len(a)*5,5)] = a

print(new_a)
```

output:

```
array([4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Comment: Thanks. Can you please explain the 4 line new_a [np.arange(0,len(a)*5,5)]=a

Comment: that piece give array([ 0,  5, 10]), which is the required location of our initial array to be placed on

Comment: How it works is that it takes start, end, step_size and then creates the sequence

Answer (score 2):

You could use `insert()` and `repeat()` to get something like:

```
>>> a = np.array([4, 2, 1])
>>> np.insert(a, np.repeat([1, 2], 4), 0)
array([4, 0, 0, 0, 0, 2, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1])
```

Answer (score 1):

Convert the array to a column, add a block of zeros on the right, flatten, and trim the extra zeros at the end:

```
np.concatenate([arr.reshape((-1, 1)), 
                np.zeros((arr.size, 4))], axis=1)\
  .reshape(-1)[:-arr.size-1]
array([4., 0., 0., 0., 0., 2., 0., 0., 0., 0., 1.])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
def insert_zeros_n(arr, n=4):
    ind = np.repeat([i+1 for i in range(len(arr)-1)], n) # where to insert zeros
    return np.insert(arr, ind, 0) # insert zeros
```

I think this function will solve your question.